# How can I CAST a variable that's passed into a method?

Tags: c#

I had this code repeated many times:

```
if (db2.Query<int>("SELECT 1 FROM CARDCHOICE WHERE CC = ?", (int)CC.JFBP1).Count == 0)
{
   var temp10 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new CardChoice { Cc = (int)CC.JFBP1, Number = i });
   db2.InsertAll(temp10);
}
```

I tried to put this into a method that I called like this

```
InsertCC(CC.JFBP1, 10);
```

Here is the method

```
private static void InsertCC(CC cc, int qty )
{
    var choice = int(cc);
    if (db2.Query<int>("SELECT 1 FROM CARDCHOICE WHERE CC = ?", choice).Count == 0)
    {
        var temp = Enumerable.Range(0, qty).Select(i => new CardChoice { Cc = choice, Number = i });
        db2.InsertAll(temp);
    }
}
```

However what happens is that it tells me I cannot CAST the cc in the method with (int) and gives me "Error expression term int"

Can someone give me some advice as to how I could cast the cc that's passed in? I realize I could do the casting in the method call but would prefer not to do that as I have a lot of those calls.

Comment: `(int)cc.JFBP1`?

Comment: If you are passing in type CC then you could just pass it in like
InsertCC(CC,10); then call CC.JFBP1 in your function.
Alternatively you could call InsertCC(CC.JFBP1,10); and change your first argument to int instead of CC.

Comment: `db2.Query<int>`? What is this? Dapper?

Comment: I think InsertCC should also return the result of the operation. So that you know if the insert was completed or skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't cast `var choice = int(cc);`

use `var choice = (int)cc;`

but you don't using `cc` parameter inside the method, so just pass `int`

```
private static void InsertCC(int choice, int qty )
{
    if (db2.Query<int>("SELECT 1 FROM CARDCHOICE WHERE CC = ?", choice).Count == 0)
    {
        var temp = Enumerable.Range(0, qty).Select(i => new CardChoice { Cc = choice, Number = i });
        db2.InsertAll(temp);
    }
}
```

then your call will work

```
InsertCC(CC.JFBP1, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake of mine. Been looking at it for a while and didn't spot that. Will accept answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: @Alan2 if you don't know how to use a cast search it on google and there will be _alot_ of information available. this should take seconds not _a while_